# Firebase - How to remove individual data from a node without removing entire node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my database looks like this:

```
MYAPP
|_______________users
|                   |__OshwYF72Jhd9bUw56W7d
|                   |                   |
|                   |                   |__username
|                   |                   |__email            
|                   |                   |__blocklist             
|                   |                             |
|                   |                             |__I7Dbys9uHwbd3s4DFXo
|                   |                             |                |__blockedId:"KbHy4293dYgVtT9pdoW"
|                   |                             |                
|                   |                             |__J7c3en8rdILxJQSA9ij
|                   |                             |                |__blockedId:"Gicuwy8r23ndoijdakr"
|                   |                             |
|                   |                             |__JicbS32uf6sg28dJD2a
|                   |                             |__GidhwgcLNA8jshda2f4
|                   |
|                   |__KbHy4293dYgVtT9pdoW
|                   |__PS8tgw53SnO892Jhweh
|                   |__Gicuwy8r23ndoijdakr
|
|__conversations
```

I'm trying to figure out the correct Firebase query to remove an individual node inside `blocklist` without deleting the other nodes.

For example, I want to delete the node that equals `blockedId:"KbHy4293dYgVtT9pdoW"` but keep the other nodes contained inside `"users/"+globaluid+"/blocklist"`

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
function unblockUser(){

    // friendToUnblock is the ID I want to remove from the block list:
    var friendToUnblock = document.getElementById('hiddenUid').innerHTML;

    // globaluid is the currently logged in user's ID:
    var blockedRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+globaluid+'/blocklist/');

    var blockedQuery = blockedRef.orderByChild('blockedId').equalTo(friendToUnblock);

        blockedQuery.once('value').then(function(blockedSnapshot) {
            blockedSnapshot.ref.remove(function (error) {

                if (!error) {
                    console.log(friendToUnblock+" should now be unblocked.");
                    }else{
                        console.log("There's been an error unblocking the user: "+error);
                    }
        });
   });              

};
```

I thought this function would target only the node that contains the matching ID and remove it, but instead it is removing every node (and so deleting the `blocklist` node in the process).

Is there a way to target and remove only the individual value contained inside the `blocklist` node without removing everything contained there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. Your query is fine, but when you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So you need to loop over those results in the callback:

```
blockedQuery.once('value').then(function(blockedSnapshot) {
    blockedSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {  
        childSnapshot.ref.remove(function (error) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log(friendToUnblock+" should now be unblocked.");
            }else{
                console.log("There's been an error unblocking the user: "+error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for explanation and answer again Frank!

Comment: To append on to Puf's answer: Since it appears that the actual keys in the blocklist are probably superfluous, you could simply key them by the blocked ids, and put the value to anything else (e.g. `true`). You can still iterate them, they work better in security rules, and you could delete them directly using `firebase.database().ref('users/'+globaluid+'/blocklist').child(idToRemove).remove();`